# Why my 2D array is not functioning right?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am newbie in C programming.I want to print 2 as my first element is 2 in the 2D array.But as i knew that n holds the first address of the array so *n should print the first element that is 2.My code

```
‪#‎include‬ <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n[3][3]={2,4,3,6,8,5,3,5,1};
printf("%d\n",*n);
return 0;
}
```

why it is printing an address.Can anyone explain it to me??

Comment: is *n is holding the first address of the array??

Comment: no..it point first row. you need `**n`.

Comment: compile using -Wall option

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your array like this:

```
int n[3][3]={{2,4,3},{6,8,5},{3,5,1}};
```

Note that the first `[3]` isn't necessary (but there's nothing wrong with specifying it). By the way, if you enable warnings, e.g. with `gcc -Wall`, the compiler will warn that there are missing braces in your initialiser.

Then to print the first value you can use:

```
printf("%d\n",n[0][0]);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
printf("%d\n",*n[0]);
```

You have an array or arrays, so this takes the zeroth element (which is an array), then dereferences it to get the zeroth value.

Answer (score 1):

A 2d array is just an array of arrays, so `*n` is actually the first subarray, to print the first element of the first subarray:

```
printf("%d\n", **n);
```

Or this is simpler and more clear:

```
printf("%d\n", n[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you got some warning on `%d` because you are not tried to print the value - just the address only.

For a 2D array, to get any value, you need to dereference twice. i.e `**n`.
`*n` is also suitable, but for a 1D array.

Here you can use either `**n`, `*n[0]` or `n[0][0]` instead of `*n`.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` would have been an array of integers, `*n` would have printed the first integer, as you are expecting.

But `n` is not that. Is a 2-dimensional array. One way of looking at it would be: an array of arrays. So in fact `*n` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an 1D array-

```
int n[9]={2,4,3,6,8,5,3,5,1};
 printf("%d\n",*n);
```

Because If you dereference the 1D array it will fetch the element. Now It will print 2.
But

```
int n[3][3]={2,4,3,6,8,5,3,5,1};
```

It is a 2D array so you need to dererence two times. If you dererence one time it will fetch the address of the array only. `n`, `n[0]`, `*n`, `&n`, `&n[0]` all will represent the starting address of it.

Try -

```
printf("%d\n",**n);
```

or

```
printf("%d\n",n[0][0]);
```